# Como não perder os dados incluídos nas Claims nas revalidações dos Cookies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Possuo uma aplicação que preciso controlar o acesso dos usuários que são de acordo com o perfíl de cada um. `Empresa`, `Filial`.

Na entidade Usuario eu adicionei os campos referentes à essas outras duas entidades e neles estarão as informações que representam cada um e seu perfíl de acesso.

```cs
public class Usuario : IdentityUser
{
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public int? FilialId { get; set; }

    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    public virtual Filial Filial { get; set; }

    public Perfil Perfil { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<Usuario> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.EMPRESA_ID, EmpresaId.ToString()));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.FILIAL_ID, FilialId?.ToString() ?? ""));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.PERFIL, Perfil.ToString());

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Para controlar o perfíl dentro da aplicação eu carrego e obtenho as informações nas Claims do usuário, como mostrado no método `GenerateUserIdentityAsync`.

E então criei uma classe `IdentityManager` para ajudar a obter tais informações e atualizá-las quando preciso.

```cs
public class IdentityManager
{
    public IdentityManager(IIdentity identity)
    {
        Identity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    }

    protected ClaimsIdentity Identity { get; set; }

    public int EmpresaId
    {
        get { return GetClaimValue(CustomClaimTypes.EMPRESA_ID); }
        set { SetClaim(CustomClaimTypes.EMPRESA_ID, value.ToString()); }
    }        

    public int? FilialId
    {
        get { return GetClaimValue(CustomClaimTypes.FILIAL_ID); }
        set { SetClaim(CustomClaimTypes.FILIAL_ID, value.ToString()); }
    }

    public Perfil Perfil
    {
        get { return (Perfil)Enum.Parse(typeof(Perfil), GetClaimValue(CustomClaimTypes.PERFIL)); }
        set { SetClaim(CustomClaimTypes.PERFIL, value.ToString()); }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, Identity);
    }

    private int GetClaimValue(string claimType)
    {
        int id;
        int.TryParse(Identity.FindFirstValue(claimType), out id);
        return id;
    }

    private void SetClaim(string claimType, string value)
    {
        var claim = Identity.FindFirst(claimType);
        if (claim != null) Identity.TryRemoveClaim(claim);
        Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, value ?? ""));
    }
}
```

Para atualiar os novos valores das Claims em IPrincipal eu executo `authenticationManager.SignIn`.

E isso funciona perfeitamente em toda a apliação até que o tempo para validação do cookie, conforme configurado no Identity, zera e a validação é refeita:

```cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity =
            SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<AppUserManager, Usuario>(

                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), // <-- Revalida os cookies de 30 em 30 minutos

                (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

Então, de 30 em 30 minutos os cookies são revalidados/reconstruídos como método `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` da classe Usuário, conforme também configurado no código acima, perdendo os dados que foram incluídos anteriormente.

A questão é que usuários com perfíl Empresa podem escolher mudar para o perfíl `Filial`, escolhendo a filial, para poder realizar operações para ela.

Por não ter acesso às informações atuais das claims dentro do método `GenerateUserIdentityAsync`, não consigo recolocá-los nas Claims.

Minha pergunta é:
**Como eu poderia fazer para não perder as informações atuais das Claims nas revalidações dos cookies feitas nos intervalos de 30 minutos (conforme configuração)?**

Estou usando o VisualStudio 2015 Community com o .Net 4.6.
Grato!

Answer (score 1):

O problema dessa revalidação é que você não guarda as informações de sessão em lugar algum. É importante entender que `Claims` são diferentes de dados de sessão.

Há duas coisas que você pode fazer:

1. Serializar a lista de `Claims` e guardar isso dentro de `Session`;
2. Usar um servidor chave-valor como o [Redis](http://redis.io/) e trazer esses dados da preferência de usuário por lá (também serializando os dados e guardando como uma *string* única).

Seja qualquer caminho que você escolha pra seguir, antes de definir os `Claims`, faça uma verificação da existência da *string* e defina os valores primeiro pela *string* se isto for possível. Caso contrário, você simplesmente preenche novamente a lista de `Claims`, como já é feito.

Comment: Fiquei curioso quanto à tabela `AspNetUserClaims` se não dá para armazenar nela. Sinceramente, ainda não vi ela sendo usada. Grato pela resposta!